# Saving Many-Many relationships Entity Framework Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I know this question has been asked multiple times, just a simple search for the title of this post will prove it, but I cannot seem to find a solution to my problem.  Here it is:

I have the following classes:

```
public class Assessor : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AssessorProductRange> ProductRange {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<AssessorAreaRange> AreaRange { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<AssessorProductRange> AssessorProductRange { get; set; }
}

public class AssessorProductRange
{
    public int? AssessorId { get; set; }
    public Assessor Assessor { get; set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following configuration (many to many)

```
public class AssessorProductRangeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<AssessorProductRange>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<AssessorProductRange> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(k => new { k.AssessorId, k.ProductId });

        builder.HasOne(o => o.Assessor)
            .WithMany(m => m.ProductRange)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.AssessorId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        builder.HasOne(o => o.Product)
            .WithMany(m => m.AssessorProductRange)
            .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
}
```

The `Assessor` class holds some information about an assessor. The `Product` class holds some information on a product/service available in the system.  The `AssessorProductRange` is a joining table between `Assessor` and `Product`.

I have a section in my website, where, you can add/edit an assessor, and either add/remove products that this assessor offers.  Here is a screenshot for reference.

[image]

When I add an assessor, the linking between the `Assessor` and `Product` works as expected, and the relevant data is saved to each individual table as expected.

When I edit an Assessor, let's say, I remove (untick) a checkbox, and save the assessor, the unticked product is not removed from the `AssessorProductRange` table.  Please note, all properties on `Assessor` object itself, for example, Initials etc update correctly.

Here is my `Update` method, with the corresponding functions.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public async Task<bool> UpdateAssessorAsync(Assessor assessor)
    {
        try
        {
            //this._repo.AttachEntity<Assessor>(assessor);
            this._repo.ModifyState<Assessor>(assessor, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified);
            this._repo.ModifyState<AssessorAreaRange>(assessor.AreaRange, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified);
            this._repo.ModifyState<AssessorProductRange>(assessor.ProductRange, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified);
            return await this._repo.SaveAsync() > 0 ? true : false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //log
            throw;
        }
    }

public void ModifyState<TEntity>(TEntity entity, EntityState state) where TEntity : class, IEntity
    {
        Context.Entry(entity).State = state;
    }

    public void ModifyState<TEntity>(ICollection<TEntity> entities, EntityState state) where TEntity : class
    {
        foreach (TEntity entity in entities)
            Context.Entry(entity).State = state;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the existing record in `AssessorProductRange` with the current `AssessorId` and the update with your new data:

```
var list = _context.AssessorProductRange.Where(s => s.AssessorId == Assessor.Id).ToList();
_context.AssessorProductRange.RemoveRange(list);
_context.Update(accessor);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```